# How to combine two hex value(High Value & Low Value) at two different array positions?

Tags: c, arduino, binary, hex

I received two hex values where at array[1] = lowbyte and at array[2] = highbyte where for my example lowbyte = 0xF4 and highbyte = 0x01 so the value will be in my example 1F4(500). So I want to combine these two values and compare but how do I do that without any library function?

Please help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What have your tutorials or text-books taught you about *unions*?

Comment: @12vi12 Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: But please be careful, and read about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Oh, and Arduinos are usually programmed in C++, which means you can't really use unions. Instead you have to solve it using bitwise operations like *shift* and *or*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude whats wrong with using unions in C++?

Comment: @DavidRanieri As far as I recall C++ doesn't allow that you write to one union member and then read back from another union member.

Comment: Re: unions & C++... It may not be officially sanctioned or portable, but (perhaps just lucky) I've used unions in CPP files to, for instance, expand/collapse 3/4 bytes for Base64 transformations... As said, it worked in my particular instance(s)... (Endianness is definitely something to be aware of!)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude endian doesn't matter in this example

Comment: @Fredrik For a solution using unions and type-punning it would.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah that's true. I was thinking about the regular shifting method :)

Comment: You should update the question to state whether you are trying to combine the two eight-bit bytes to get a 16-bit unsigned integer, a 16-bit two’s complement signed integer, or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and I found this as my solution and it seems to be working fine:

```
int temp = (short)(((HIGHBYTE) & 0xFF) << 8 | (LOWBYTE) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Glad you succeeded... If HIGHBYTE and LOWBYTE truly are `unsigned char` types, there should be no need to `& 0xFF`. (There would be no higher order bits...) Congratulations.

Comment: Just noticed that, after combining into a 'signed short', you are storing the value into a `signed int`... You are the only one who knows if the data values are signed or unsigned... This may be a concern... Does `arr[1] = 0x80` give you the signed/unsigned result you need?

Comment: Sorry , for forgetting to mention the datatype but the values are stored in unsigned char.

Comment: this will do for you `(HIGHBYTE << 8) | LOWBYTE`

Comment: In C implementations where `int` is 16 bits, the behavior of `((HIGHBYTE) & 0xFF) << 8` is not defined by the C standard when `HIGHBYTE` is 128 or greater, because the value is not representable in an `int`. If `int` is wider but `short` is 16 bits, then the cast to `short` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic example showing how to combine values of two different variables into one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
  char highbyte = 0x01;
  unsigned char lowbyte = 0xF4; //Edited as per comments from @Fe2O3, 
  short int val = 0;

  val = (highbyte << 8) | lowbyte; // If lowbyte declared as signed, then masking is required `lowbyte & 0xFF`
  printf("0x%hx\n", val);
  return 0;

}
```

Tested this on Linux PC.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I write like this `val = (highbyte << 8) | (lowbyte);` I am getting `0xfff4` in output. But yes, `0x00FF` and `0xFF` mean the same thing.

Comment: Declare `lowbyte` as `unsigned char`... The problem you see is because the compiler has done sign extension when promoting `lowbyte` for the processing... There's no 'sign bit' in the low half (or quarter) of an integer datatype, is there?

Comment: @Fe2O3 That's the reason I Love Stack Overflow cause I get to understand from expert and experienced people like you!

Comment: "Expert"? no. "Experienced"? yes. Now, don't forget to edit your answer to drop the 'masking' and use an `unsigned char` low byte (perhaps explaining why in a "//" comment.) Cheers, and happy coding...

Comment: This code has several defects. If `char` is unsigned (the C standard allows it to be signed or unsigned), and `int` is 16 bits, then the behavior of `highbyte << 8` is undefined when `highbyte` is 128 or greater, because the value is not representable in an `int`. If `char` is signed and `highbyte` is negative, the behavior of `highbyte << 8` is not defined because the C standard does not define left-shifts of negative values.

Comment: In the case when `char` is unsigned, `int` is wider than 16 bits, `short` is 16 bits, and `highbyte` is 128 or greater, the result of assignment to `val` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer where you converted to short, it seems you may want to combine the two bytes to produce a 16-bit two’s complement integer. This answer shows how to do that in three ways for which the behavior is fully defined by the C standard, as well as a fourth way that requires knowledge of the C implementation being used. Methods 1 and 3 are also defined in C++.

Given two eight-bit unsigned bytes with the more significant byte in `highbyte` and the less significant byte in `lowbyte`, four options for constructing the 16-bit two’s complement value they represent are:

1. Assemble the bytes in the desired order and copy them into an `int16_t`: `uint16_t t = (uint16_t) highbyte << 8 | lowbyte; int16_t result; memcpy(&result, &t, sizeof result);`.
2. Assemble the bytes in the desired order and use a union to reinterpret them: `int16_t result = (union { uint16_t u; int16_t i; }) { (uint16_t) highbyte << 8 | lowbyte } .i;`.
3. Construct the result arithmetically: `int16_t result = ((highbyte ^ 128) - 128) * 256 + lowbyte;`.
4. If it is given that the code will be used only with C implementations that define conversion to a signed integer to wrap, then a conversion may be used: `int16_t result = (int16_t) ((uint16_t) highbyte << 8 | lowbyte);`.

(In the last, the conversion to `int16_t` is implicit in the initialization, but a cast is used because, without it, some compilers will produce a warning or error, depending on switches.)

Note: `int16_t` and `uint16_t` are defined by including `<stdint.h>`. Alternatively, if it is given that `short` is 16 bits, then `short` and `unsigned short` may be used in place of `int16_t` and `uint16_t`.

Here is more information about the first three of these.

### 1. Assemble the bytes and copy

`(uint16_t) highbyte << 8 | lowbyte` converts to a type suitable for shifting without sign-bit issues, moves the more significant byte into the upper 8 bits of 16, and puts the less significant byte into the lower 8 bits.

Then `uint16_t = …;` puts those bits into a `uint16_t`.

`memcpy(&result, &t, sizeof result);` copies those bits into an `int16_t`. C 2018 7.20.1.1 1 guarantees that `int16_t` uses two’s complement. C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 guarantees that the value bits in `int16_t` have the same position values as their counterparts in `uint16_t`, so the copy produces the desired arrangement in `result`.

### 2. Assemble the bytes and use a union

`(type) { initial value }` is a *compound literal*. `(union { uint16_t u; int16_t i; }) { (uint16_t) highbyte << 8 | lowbyte }` makes a compound literal that is a union and initializes its `u` member to have the value described above. Then `.i` reads the `i` member of the union, which reinterprets the bits using the type `int16_t`, which is two’s complement as describe above. Then `int16_t result = …;` initializes `result` to this value.

### 3. Construct the result arithmetically

Here we start with the more significant byte separately, interpreting the eight bits of `highbyte` as two’s complement. In eight-bit two’s complement, the sign bit represents 0 if it is off and −128 if it is on. (For example, 11111100<sub>2</sub> as unsigned binary represents 128+64+32+16+8+4 =252, but, in two’s complement, it is −128+64+32+16+8+4 = −4.)

Consider `highbyte ^ 128) - 128`. If the first bit is off, `^ 128` turns it on, which adds 128 to its unsigned binary meaning. Then `- 128` subtracts 128, producing a net effect of zero. If the first bit is on, `^ 128` turns it off, which cancels its unsigned binary meaning. Then `- 128` gives the desired value. Thus `(highbyte ^ 128) - 128` reinterprets the first bit to have a value of 0 if it is off and −128 if it is on.

Then `((highbyte ^ 128) - 128) * 256` moves this to the more significant byte of 16 bits (in an `int` type at this point), and `+ lowbyte` puts the less significant byte in the less significant position. And of course `int16_t result = …;` initializes `result` to this computed value.